# При загрузке Tesseract tess two ошибка error (19 0) SDK location not found

Tags: android

При загрузке Tesseract tess two https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/tree/master/tess-two  из Android studio  ошибка error (19 0) SDK location not found  Не подскажите что сделать чтобы загрузить проект?

Comment: установить 19 SDK, или поменять targetSDK На установленную у вас версию

Comment: я думал          dependencies не прописал 
    compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.3'   а когда прописал снова ошибку получил Error:Circular reference between projects: :tess-two -> :tess-two  Сейчас попробую ваш вариант.

Comment: поменял как вы сказали снова ошибка Error:Execution failed for task ':tess-two:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно Android Studio не знает где у вас лежит SDK. В корне проекта создайте файл local.properties и запишите в него строку типа 
Windows: "sdk.dir=E:\Android\sdk"
Linux: "sdk.dir=/home/sdk"
Писать только то что в кавычках(без кавычек) в зависимости от вашей ОС

Comment: Путь правильно прописан sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\tylkovich\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk